# Find a bijection, check if a given set is a function

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I have problems with two exercises:

$1)$ Find a bijection between $A$ and $B$.

$$A=[0,1) \times[0,1)$$
$$B=\{{<x,y>}\in \mathbb R^2: x,y>0,\ x+y<1\}$$

$2)$ Decide if the given set is a function.

$$\{<x,f>: x\in \mathbb R \ \ \wedge f: \mathbb R\to \mathbb R \ \ \wedge \forall _{r \in \mathbb R} [f(r)=x] \}$$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! You are more likely to get a good answer if you give us more information. For example, what have you tried? At which step are you stuck? What level answer are you looking for? And your notation: is $<x,y>$ an ordered pair? Is $R$ the set of real numbers?

Comment: Hello! Sorry for no posting my effort but to be honest I'm not good with this type of tasks and I don't know how to do it yet. Yes $<x,y>$ is an ordered pair and $R$ is set of reals

Comment: I like the first one! The border of $A$ is partly included in $A$. You should get rid of it. Then try to extend to a full bijection.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "upvote" and/or "accept" the answer by clicking the up arrow and the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Answer (score 0):

For 1);

How explicit do you need to be?

If you are given a bijection $[0,1) \rightarrow (0,k)$ for each $k > 0$, can you think of a way to create a bijection $A \rightarrow B$?

Can you think of a way to create a bijection $[0,1) \rightarrow (0,k)$?

(A few hints in the comments so a little easier to not read if you want to think first)

For 2);

A set of ordered pairs defines a function $A \rightarrow B$ iff for every $a \in A$ there is a unique $b \in B$ such that $<a,b>$ is in your set.

So to decide if the given set is a function, check if:

1. for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ there exists some $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\forall r \in \mathbb{R} f(r) = x$
2. whenever $<x,g>$ and $<x,h>$ are in the given set $\{ <x,f> : x \in \mathbb{R}, f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \forall r \in \mathbb{R} f(r) = x \}$, we have $g = h$.

This should be easy to check.

Comment: Hints: bijections from [0,1) to (0,k) exist by piecing together ones from [a,b) to [c,d) (or (c,d]) created by translation and scaling (and reflection). This is possible in two pieces.

For $A \rightarrow B$, what can you do if you send $(r,s)$ to the ordered pair with first element $\varphi (r)$, where $\varphi$ is a bijection from $[0,1)$ to $(0,1)$?